# Buildroot ignoring configuration files - building wrong kernel

Tags: kernel, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot to create a Linux system for the NXP LPC3250 microcontroller.

There are patches to the vanilla kernel to make it compatible with the LPC3250 controller:
http://git.lpclinux.com/

I would like to build Kernel 2.6.39.2, but my Buildroot system always makes a 2.6.34 kernel!

I have set the GIT repository to point to 2.6.39.2:
[image]

You can see that I've specified a Defconfig for the system I'm building for: `ea3250`

I've edited my ea3250 defconfig as well:
[image]

After doing a `make clean all` to clean everything and rebuild the system, looking inside the output kernel image shows it is still building 2.6.34:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another menu I need to configure to get it to build 2.6.39.2?

Comment: What buildroot version did you install?

Comment: I had some unstable version, I guess. Didn't really pay attention, just pulled down a copy from CVS. I ended up getting version 2012.11 and everything builds fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but it doesn't fit a comment due to formatting:

What happens when you do the following:

```
cd /home/user/projects/buildroot
make clean
make distclean
```

Copy target system's `/proc/config.gz` to host `/tmp`
Then take the existing kernel config and translates it to the new kernel version by answering the various question:

```
gunzip -c /tmp/config.gz ./.config
make oldconfig
```

Do some sanity checking on version:

```
make menuconfig
```

Build the binaries

```
make
```

Check version of the kernel image built, don't load the kernel image in nano to search for a string, that is bad practice.

```
file ./buildroot/output/images/*
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment on version helped me, so I will just accept this. :)